# Как преобразовать данные в число в powerapps?

Tags: типы, office365

Есть приложение powerapps, в приложении - экран, на экране - форма, значение которой стоит на "число".
[image: форма в приложении]

Есть подключенная таблица, которая хранится на шарпоинте, там помимо всего прочего есть столбец "моточасы", который - число.

[image: Таблица в шарпоинте]

Я создаю кнопку и пишу условие, что если поле не пустое - занести значение в таблицу.

```
If(
    !IsBlank(TextInput1);
    Navigate(MainScreen)&&
    Collect(Table1; {
        Показание:TextInput1;
        });
    Set(gvBorderColor; Red)&&
    SetFocus(TextInput1)
    )
```

И получаю ошибку несоответствия типа.

[image: Ошибка]

Но я ведь и передаю число. Нет?
Ну ладно, пробую Показание:Value(TextInput1); и Показание:Value(TextInput1.text); и... Ничего! Ошибка так и висит, строка не добавляется.

Я то-то не так делаю с синтаксисом или это всё-таки что-то с типом данных?

Comment: Почему установлена метка VBA, хотя код не VBA? Принимается и другое решение?

Comment: Я не уверен по поводу VBA, но это Microsoft и синтаксис похож...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в понимании синтаксиса. Правильно писать Показание:TextInput1.Text

Answer (score 0):

Решение на `VBA`. Возможно, поможет понять ошибку.

В поле на форме число в текстовом формате, в таблице - число.

`Val(текст)` (не `Value(текст)`!) возьмет из текста только число до первого нечислового символа (исключая разделитель)

Например:

```
Val("52abc") = 52
Val("52,5abc") = 52
Val("52.5abc") = 52,5
Val("a52.5") = 0
```

Если оператор `Val` не подходит, проверка на число:

```
If IsNumeric(поле_на_форме) Then 
     If CDbl(поле_на_форме) = значение_таблицы Then 
          ' чего-то делаем'
     End If
Else
     ' кричим об ошибке'
End If
```